# Excelで、虫食い状になっている実績を検出したい

Tags: vba, excel

例えば以下のような表があったとき、飛び飛びについている０の個数を検出したいです。

```
実績A　１　１　１　１　１　１　１　１　１
実績B　１　１　０　１　０　１　１　１　１
実績C　１　１　０　０　０　０　１　１　１
実績D　０　０　０　１　１　１　０　０　０
実績E　１　１　１　１　１　０　０　０　０
```

例の場合、実績B、Cのように、０が１に挟まれている状態がNGです。実績Bは２個、Cは４個です。
実績DとEは、０は存在しますが、最初から連続している、または最後まで連続していて、１に挟まれていないのでOKです。

いいアイデアがあればアドバイスいただけると嬉しいです。

Comment: 質問が「０の個数を検出したい」であればOK / NGではなく、各実績に対しどのような集計結果になってほしいかを明示された方が質問としてわかりやすいのではないでしょうか？

Comment: 解決するのが難しい場合、まずは問題を単純化して取り組んでみるのも一つの方法だと思います。今回の場合なら「飛び飛びか」は一旦抜きにして「行ごとに0の個数を数える」など。 / 現状だと「やりたいこと」が書かれているだけで、「ロジックが思いつかない」のか「そもそもVBAの文法が分からない」のかが読み取れません。そのあたりも踏まえて質問文を見直してみてください。

Comment: ちなみに質問記事内では全角の`０`,`１`かつ文字間は全角空白が使われていますが、実際もそうですか？ それともそれは単に見易さのためで本当は半角数字で各セルに分かれて格納されていますか？ データは説明用のサンプルであってもなるべく実態に即した内容にした方が良いと思われます。

Comment: みなさん、フィードバック感謝いたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- 先頭から連続する`0`をスキップ、つまり最初に出現する`1`を探す
- 同様に末尾に連続する`0`をスキップ、つまり最後に出現する`1`を探す
- これによって縮小された範囲の中で`0`をカウント

で得られるのではありませんか？

仮に検索範囲を`$B1:$J1`としたら

```
=LET(
    DATA, $B1:$J1,
    START, XMATCH(1, DATA, 0, 1),
    END, XMATCH(1, DATA, 0, -1),
    COUNTIF(OFFSET(DATA, 0, START-1, 1, END-START+1), 0)
)
```

でできるかと。例示されている通り横並びで計算しましたが縦並びの場合は[`OFFSET`関数](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/office/offset-%E9%96%A2%E6%95%B0-c8de19ae-dd79-4b9b-a14e-b4d906d11b66)に与える引数を変えてください。

Comment: 解決いたしました！縮小された範囲でカウントは、僕では考え付きませんでした。
ご回答ありがとうございました。